# How do I make knitr::kable tables stop floating?

Tags: r, knitr

When I use a `knitr::kable` in a latex doc, the table floats.  How do I stop it from floating?

Comment: have you read the advice in the bookdown book? https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html
This uses the argument ? longtable = T` and the Latex-command `\usepackage{longtable}`

Comment: Sweet! If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the argument `longtable = T` in `knitr::kable()` and add `\ usepackage{longtable}` in the YAML header:

````
---
title: "Using longtable in RMD"
output: pdf_document
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
author: Author
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{longtable}
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(cars, longtable = T)
```
````

Comment: I'm actually using LaTeX knitr, not markdown, so that \usepackage is not in a YAML header. Also, I say longtable=TRUE, not longtable=T. But, I'll accept this, why not.

Comment: Also kableExtra solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850011/how-to-stop-bookdown-tables-from-floating-to-bottom-of-the-page-in-pdf