# How to stop bookdown tables from floating to bottom of the page in pdf?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using `bookdown` to create pdf reports, but my tables are all floating down to the bottom of the page, regardless of how much space there is. See this example:

````
---
title: "test_doc"
author: "Jake Thompson"
date: "6/30/2017"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, collapse = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

# Test heading

Let make a data frame and print it in Table \@ref(tab:test-table)

```{r test-table}
data_frame(col_a = seq_len(5), col_b = rnorm(5), col_c = runif(5)) %>%
  knitr::kable(caption = "This is a test")
```
````

The resulting pdf looks like this:

[image: pdf-output]

Why does the table go to the bottom of the page? And is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: For why, please read https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html. For how to prevent it, I'll leave it to other LaTeX experts to answer you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can solve this problem with `kableExtra` by

```
data_frame(col_a = seq_len(5), col_b = rnorm(5), col_c = runif(5)) %>%
  knitr::kable(caption = "This is a test") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```

It basically insert a `[!h]` to the LaTeX `table` environment which will prevent the floating behavior and pin the table at current location.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks Hao, I keep finding your lovely help scattered throughout the internet..

Comment: @Nova haha, glad it helps! :D

Comment: If, like me, you encounter the same problem simultanously for figures, here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc/33801326#33801326

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment that you must call the dataframe in the chunk first as shown in the answer. If you use the code below it will not work 

    
      `knitr::kable(myDataFrame, caption = "This is a test") %>%
      kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")`

Answer (score 10):

I had to use

```
kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```

Note the uppercase HOLD_position, different from hold_position.  See also [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.1.0/topics/kable_styling).

To be able to use that, I also had to add to the top section of the doc (from [How to build a latex kable through bookdown::render_book?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61780333)):

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
```

Comment: I'll reiterate that `HOLD_position` worked whereas `hold_position` did not for me.