# Placement of pictures in markdown/bookdown

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

I am writing a text in bookdown with Rstudio and want to include a picture within the text like this:

````
Some text goes here

```{r, fig.cap="\\label{fig:figs}figlabel"}
knitr::include_graphics("images/image.png")
```
Some other text goes here.
````

However, when I render the book with bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd"), The inserted picture is placed on the next page rather than where it is placed in the text. I want it to be placed between the two sentences, but it is placed below the last one.

Is there a way to control where in the text the image is rendered? I have tried to look at [chunk options for images](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots), and also in the [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html), but neither seem to document ways to control placement of figures.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44888475/9941039 May this will help you

Comment: The link in this comment only works for table at the moment, not with figures. See this thread instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc/33801326#33801326

(no satisfactory solution so far.)

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX will try to find an optimal location for the figure. You can force the placement of floating figures and tables with `\FloatBarrier`. Note that doing so, you might end up with a lot of white space on the bottom of the page.

````
Some text goes here. See fig. \@ref(fig:my-fig)

```{r my-fig, fig.cap="fig caption"}
knitr::include_graphics("images/image.png")
```

\FloatBarrier

Some other text goes here.
````