# I use kable in R Markdown and add caption to my table, in the output PDF file, the table drop to the bottom of page

Tags: r, knitr, kable

In R Markdown file, I use kable to create my table, I use argument "caption" to add title to my table, but once I add this caption, in the out put PDF file, the table I created will directly drop to the bottom of the pages, once I delete  this caption, it went back to where it should be.

I tried in different laptop, it`s all the same.

````
---
title: "MA615_sep_13"
author: "KC"
date: "9/18/2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(esquisse)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
library(tinytex)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

**Class assignment**

Using the MPG dataset, which is available with the ggplot2 library, produce a document that includes the following elements: headers, text, tables, and plots.

Tables should include a comparison of city and highway mileage by the class of car and the best three car models for city and highway mileage for all the years in which data is available.

Plot the data displaying as much of the data as you can. Put continuous variables on the axes and include a locally smoothed regression line to show the relationship with mileage.  Also make a box plot comparing city and highway MPG by class of car.

**Table One**:

```
data(mpg)
mpg_1=select(mpg,cty,hwy,class)
mpg_1 %<>% group_by(class)%>%
  summarise(City=mean(cty),Highway=mean(hwy))%>%
  arrange(class,City,Highway)
mpg_1 = mpg_1[order(mpg_1$City,decreasing = TRUE),]
# kable(mpg_1,format = 'latex',align = "c",
#       col.names = c('Class','City MPG','Highway MPG'),
#       booktabs = TRUE,
#       digits = 2,
#       caption = "Average City and Highway MPG by Car Class")0
knitr::kable(mpg_1,digits = 2,align = 'c',
             col.names = c('Class','City MPG','Highway MPG'),
             booktabs = TRUE,
             caption = 'Average City and Highway MPG by Car Class')
```

Comment: If you don't want table moves from its place, you may try with ` %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options =c("hold_position"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop bookdown tables from floating to bottom of the page in pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850011/how-to-stop-bookdown-tables-from-floating-to-bottom-of-the-page-in-pdf)