# How to build a latex kable through bookdown::render_book?

Tags: r, bookdown

Here is a file `kable.Rmd` that knits properly in RStudio:

````
---
title: "latex kable"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r table1, echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "repeat_header"),
                full_width = F)
```
````

The output shows a table:

[image]

Here is a YAML file to configure bookdown called `kable_bookdown.yml`:

```
# See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html
rmd_files: ["kable.Rmd"]
delete_merged_file: true
```

Here is a call to render:

```
bookdown::render_book(input='kable.Rmd', config_file='kable_bookdown.yml')
```

Here is the error I get from that render:

> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS _main.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output _main.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \rowcolor
```

The `rowcolor` likely comes from the `"striped"` latex option.

Why does it work in RStudio, but not through the render call?

RStudio seems to be using the same latex (pdflatex).

I'm using RStudio Version 1.2.5042, R 3.6.3, bookdown 0.18, kableExtra 1.1.0, knitr 1.28, tinytex 0.20.

**EDIT**: I was not able to get `header_includes` to work.  Adding this to `kable.Rmd` worked for me:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
```

**EDIT 2**: This also worked for me (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown)):

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    # list latex packages:
    extra_dependencies: ["colortbl", "xcolor"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `kableExtra` adds extra packages to the `.tex` header, and those are getting lost when `bookdown` does the processing.  I believe `\rowcolor` comes from the `colortbl` package.  So you need to tell `bookdown` to include that package.  If I put this line into the YAML in `kable.Rmd`, it works:

```
header_includes: "colortbl"
```

but in a more complicated example, you may need more includes.  Here are the ones that `kableExtra` causes to be inserted:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Comment: Thanks! I could not get `header_includes` to work. See my EDIT above. If you change your answer to something that works for me, I'd be delighted to accept it.

Comment: Also: any ideas why bookdown acts differently from the "knit" render for these includes?

Comment: I'm seeing inconsistent results with both your edits and mine.  Not sure what's going on.